# Best practice / best services for going online and interactive with a mobile (Android) game

Tags: java, android, web-services

I would like to create a multiplayer turn game, in which users authenticate (through a Facebook account) and eventually play some games against other players.

I assume I need a server that, through some sql query, keeps specular authentication on its side and can store and retrieve information about the ongoing matches and whatever else. There's no need to any web server, so the server would actually only have these two roles: authenticate and store information.

I actually already have the game and I already authenticate with FB, but don't go further as soon as I currently don't have any dedicated server for this.

As soon as this - I suppose - is a very common situation for anyone that would like to make interactive his own mobile game, before starting this long journey I was wondering if there is something already made: libraries that I could use both on server and on client side, or even online services ready to be used, with facebook synced authentication and a few commands to enter the very few information that is needed for my game to run, without having to fight with security problems, syncronization issues and whatever else may arise.

Also templates, tutorials or complete examples (both sides, server and client) are welcome

Thank you very much.

Comment: Google App Engine may be a good start. It requires some modifications to the client, but server setup should be fairly straight forward. It is also free until you reach a certain number of daily users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually a lot of full solutions for your game.

You will need a strong server side and a lot of server logic. But again you can use existing services that handle the server side for you. http://www.skiller-games.com/ has good support and monetization features.

Others:

- http://www.scoreloop.com/
- http://www.exitgames.com/

If you really want to make everything your own, you need to read up on some networking.

[how to make Multiplayer Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687598/how-to-make-multiplayer-game)

Comment: No no no, thank you! I'm rather expert of networking (it was my previous job), but I absolutely don't want to face this challenge. What I am looking for is something "ready".
I'll check those out, as a first case anyway you suggest me skiller-games, right? thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah skiller-games is a very good full solution for most of your problems. I've had many more bookmarked but can't find them now. I'll let you know if I find them. Hope my current answer is enough for the question. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry if I bother you, I really cannot find anything on skiller site about the costs. Is it free, as you know? Thank you.

Comment: Skiller works with revenue shares, the rest is free.  http://www.skiller-games.com/develua.aspx