# What do I need in order to start creating an android game similar to clash of clans?

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries, google-play-games

I've been working with java for a while now, and now want to dive into making a game similar to Clash of Clans/building/empire games.

I've already install the Android SDK and set up a project, but I was wondering what tools do I really need to start working on this?

1) Do I need a different SDK to create Apps on phone vs. tablet?

2) Are there any libraries that I should be looking at, because right now I have nothing.

3) What other things do I need?

Comment: `What do I need in order to start creating an android game similar to clash of clans?` Expensive servers and Google.com

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should decide if your game is going to be 2D or 3D. After that, you need an engine... 
http://mobilegameengines.com/android/game_engines 
and
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/1821

If you are going to make a 2D game, in my opinion AndEngine is very good. Also, you should decide for which platform are you going to create a game. If you target only Android, Java engines can be used. If you are targeting iOS or some other platform, you should use some engine which uses OpenGL ES 2.0.

Also, you need a Physics Engine. For example Box2D http://box2d.org/.

As Nicolas suggested, you should consider a multiplayer aspect. This is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687623/1374065

Games like Clash of Clans are complex, so there are many aspect which should be carefully considered.